# QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component, plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick, qtquick2plugin.dll: Thespecifiedmodulecoul not be found

Tags: python, qml, pyside2

See This Error Message Which I Got From Qt Creator

[image]

I Am Currently Learning QT Creator.

When i click on the run button, it shows me the error

Here is the source code for main.qml file :

```py
#THis is main.qml file 

import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
}
```

```py
#This is the main.py file

# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
import os

from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml"))

    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

```py
# This is main.pyproject file

{
    "files": ["main.py", "main.qml"]
}
```

Comment: It seems that for some reason that .dll was deleted, I recommend you reinstall pyside2 disabling your antivirus

Comment: I Checked out the locations, the dll is there! and my antivirus are always disabled !

Comment: So that .dll is corrupted

Comment: uninstalled and reinstalled again bruhh, still same one!

Comment: WARNING: The scripts pyside2-designer.exe, pyside2-lupdate.exe, pyside2-rcc.exe and pyside2-uic.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\MURALIRAJAN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
WARNING: Value for scheme.headers does not match. Please report this to <https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9617>
distutils: C:\Users\MURALIRAJAN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.

Comment: I Got the above specific warning! however it said it installed successfully!

Comment: Do what it says: add  `C:\Users\MURALIRAJAN\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts` to the PATH of environment variables.

Comment: Done, but still the same error !

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding details in comments. Code is hard to read in comments, and comments appear in order of votes, not chronologically.

Answer (score 0):

finally found an Answer!, my qtquick DLL is already there and it is not corrupted, the thing is when I'm creating a project in qt creator I selected lower version of pyside!

Stack Overflow what you guys should do is, when creating a new project select the latest [Top one] version of the pyside and create your project!